# Condensation pipe from air handler is making gargling sound

Tags: hvac, furnace, pump, condensation, leaking

I would appreciate some help on a new gargling voice coming from my HVAC furnace (first time using this season - this didn't happen last year).

As shown in picture, there are 2 small tubes coming out of the air handler going into a kind of 'overflow' box (gray one mounted to the unit) which then overflows into the condensation pump. There is a very strange gargling voice coming from these tubes/ gray box, I'm thinking there should not be water in this as it is like trying to pull air inside from it. Is this normal? What could be the issue? The main pump is working fine and draining all water automatically.
[image: Condensation tubes from furnace air handler]
[image: Updated the picture to show full picture]

Comment: Where does the white PVC pipe go?

Comment: Are you certain the sound is coming from that grey funnel? Is it blocked up at all? Maybe some spiders moved in and built a web in there, partially blocking it?

Comment: That just circles back to the condensation pump. I'm uploading a picture of the full thing in OP. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @FreeMan - the noise is not from the gray funnel.. it is coming from the black tubes submerged in the condensation water and some bubbles coming out of the tubes.

Comment: So are those black tubes always submerged in water a normal thing? Because as you see - it would only drain to the pump when the water reaches overflow funnel height.

Comment: I would guess that the black tubes run into a chamber which is slightly pressurized by the air circulation fan.  The setup is just blowing bubbles.

Comment: So it looks like it was a 'new season' kink. I sucked out all water from the gray overflow box and started again, as expected it started dripping condensation and filled up the gray box - which then normally overflows to the pump box. No more bubbles and no more noise. The tubes stay in water and no gargling sound.. I guess I just incorrectly thought these were 'air flow' tubes and not water/ condensation tubes.